# I am trying to build a python GUI Database Comparator using PySimpleGUI i missing something here?

Tags: python, pandas, cx-oracle, pysimplegui

I am trying to Build a GUI DB Comparator which is divided in two layout window.

1. Get the DB Detail from user and Test the connection
2. Get a Excel file which contains the SQL Statement that will be performed on DB and using Datacompy Comparison will be displayed to the user.

Problem I am facing right now is

1. DB Details should be on top and the Output box should be below them but it's vice versa
2. While after taking the input ( DB Details ) when i click on DB Test1 button application close's itself without displaying what went wrong ( No Code error, just went off )

I am new to PySimpleGUI, might have made slilly mistakes, Please guide me through the error and statement which i need to re enter.

Here's the code of First layout window :

```
 import PySimpleGUI as sg
 import re
 import datacompy
 import cx_Oracle
 import pandas as pd


 def read_query(connection, query):
     cursor = connection.cursor()
        try:
           cursor.execute( query )
           header = [ x[0] for x in cursor.description]
           rows = cursor.fetchall()
           return header, rows
       finally:
           if cursor is not None:
           cursor.close()

  def createCon(uname,passw,hname,portnum,sname):

    dsn_str = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host=hname,
                            port=portnum,
                            service_name = sname)
    con = cx_Oracle.connect(user = uname,
                        password = passw,
                        dsn = dsn_str)
    if con == True:
        return con
    else:
        return 0
      


  DB_creds_one = [
     [
        sg.Text("UserName"),
        sg.In(size=(30, 2), enable_events=True, key="-uname_db1-")
     ],
     [
        sg.Text("Password"),
        sg.In(size=(30, 1), enable_events=True, key="-pword_db1-")
     ],
     [
        sg.Text("Hostname"),
        sg.In(size=(30, 1), enable_events=True, key="-hname_db1-")
     ],
     [
        sg.Text("Service Name"),
        sg.In(size=(30, 1), enable_events=True, key="-sname_db1-")
     ],
     [
        sg.Text("Port"),
        sg.In(size=(30, 1), enable_events=True, key="-port_db1-")
     ],
     [   
        sg.Button('Test Con1', key='B1')
     ],

   ]

  DB_creds_two = [
    [
        sg.Text("UserName"),
        sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-uname_db2-")
    ],
    [
        sg.Text("Password"),
        sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-pword_db2-")
    ],
    [
        sg.Text("Hostname"),
        sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-hname_db2-")
    ],
    [
        sg.Text("Service Name"),
        sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-sname_db2-")
    ],
    [
        sg.Text("Port"),
        sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-port_db2-")
    ],
    [   
        sg.Button('Test Con2',key='B2')
    ],

  ]


layoutprefile = [
    [
        sg.Column(DB_creds_one),
        sg.VSeperator(),
        sg.Column(DB_creds_two),
       [sg.Output(size=(61, 5), key='-output-')],
       [sg.Submit('Proceed'), sg.Cancel('Exit')]
    
    ]
]
 

 window = sg.Window("DB Comparator", layoutprefile)

 while True:    # The Event Loop
    event, values = window.read()
    # print(event, values)  # debug
    if event in (None, 'Exit', 'Cancel'):
         secondwindow = 0
         break
    elif event == 'B1':
         # Test DB Connection 1  return Test_DB1
         uname_d1 = window.FindElement('-uname_db1-')
         pword_d1 = window.FindElement('-pword_db1-')
         hname_d1 = window.FindElement('-hname_db1-')
         sname_d1 = window.FindElement('-sname_db1-')
         port_d1 = window.FindElement('-port_db1-')
         
         if uname_d1 and pword_d1 and hname_d1 and sname_d1 and port_d1 == "":
               print("ENter values")
         else:
               Test_DB1 = createCon(uname_d1,pword_d1,hname_d1,sname_d1,port_d1)
     elif event == 'B2':
        # Test DB Connection 2 return Test_DB2
        uname_d2 = window.FindElement('-uname_db2-')
        pword_d2 = window.FindElement('-pword_db2-')
        hname_d2 = window.FindElement('-hname_db2-')
        sname_d2 = window.FindElement('-sname_db2-')
        port_d2 = window.FindElement('-port_db2-')
        if uname_d2 and pword_d2 and hname_d2 and sname_d2 and port_d2 == "":
             print("ENter values")
        else:
             Test_DB2 = createCon(uname_d2,pword_d2,hname_d2,sname_d2,port_d2)

    if event == 'Proceed':
        if (Test_DB1 and Test_DB2 != 'True'):
            secondwindow = 0
            sg.Popup("Incorrect Database Details Please Verify the Connection Again")
        else:
            window.close()
            secondwindow = 1
            break

if secondwindow != 1:
   exit()
```

Comment: and one more request i am also trying to append all the error's into output window instead of using print, if anyone help me out in using .append function ?

Comment: solution to sending `print` to window you can find in many GUIs in Python. For sure you can find for `tkitner` - it can be even in Python documentation. You have to create class with method `write(text)` which send `text` to your widget, and you have to assign it to `sys.stdout` - and then `print` which normally use `sys.stdout.write(text)` to send it on screen it will use your `write(text)` to send it to your widget. I'm not sure but `PySimpleGUI` may aready have widget for this and it may automatiically get all prints. Or maybe it was console in window.

Comment: maybe it close without error but because you run `break` to exit event loop. Simply use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables - it is called `"print debuging"`

Comment: instead of `0`, `1` in `secondwindow` you could use `False`, `True` - it will be more readable. And in `createCon` you could remove `else: return 0` and it will run automatically `return None` - and `None` is more readble then `0`. Or maybe you should use `return con` without any `if/else`. If you get `False` in `con` then `return con` will send `False` and it will be even more readable then `None`

Comment: it is wrong `uname_d1 and pword_d1 and hname_d1 and sname_d1 and port_d1 == "":` it has to be `uname_d1 == "" and pword_d1 == "" and hname_d1 == "" and sname_d1 == "" and port_d1 == "":`. It this situation you can also write it shorter with `==` instead of `and` - `uname_d1 == pword_d1 == hname_d1 == sname_d1 == port_d1 == "":`. But maybe you should use `or`. The same problem with `Test_DB1 and Test_DB2 != 'True'` - and use `True`, not string `'True'` - `Test_DB1 != True and Test_DB2 != True` or better `Test_DB1 is not True and Test_DB2 is not True` or shorter `not Test_DB1 and not Test_DB2`

Comment: is your code run? it gives me error because layout has `[ ]` in wrong place. After modification it start correctly and it even show `Output` which display text from `print()`

Comment: BTW: maybe this was your problem - you have `Output` so all error messages are send to `Output` and you don't see them . Maybe first try code without `Output`

Comment: with your code I don't see any `Output` in window - and when I set correct `[ ]` then I see `Output` below `Details` - so I don't how you could have `Output` above `Details`. Simply you use `[ ]` in wrong places. Or you run totally different code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how this code could work. It was giving me message that layout has wrong `[]` - and maybe because this I didn't have `sg.Output` in window. But it was still used and all error messages was send to `sg.Output` and you could not see error.

Correct layout

```
layoutprefile = [
    [ 
        sg.Column(DB_creds_one),
        sg.VSeperator(),
        sg.Column(DB_creds_two),
    ],

    [sg.Output(size=(61, 5), key='-output-')],
    [sg.Submit('Proceed'), sg.Cancel('Exit')]
]
```

and now it display me `sg.Output` at the bottom of window. And all `print()` and error messages are send to this widget. But it can be better to remove `Output` for some time to see all errors in normal console.

---

You have other problems

it should be with `or` and with `== ""` for all variables - to check if at least one element is empty

```
if uname_d1 == '' or pword_d1 == '' or hname_d1 == '' or sname_d1 == '' or port_d1 == '':
```

or you could check it as

```
if '' in (uname_d1, pword_d1, hname_d1, sname_d1, port_d1):
```

Eventually you can use fact that empty string is treated as `False`

```
if not all([uname_d2, pword_d2, hname_d2, sname_d2, port_d2]):
```

But there is other problem. Using `window.FindElement('-uname_db1-')` you get widget and to get text from widget you need `.get()` or you should use `values[..]`

```
uname_d1 = window.FindElement('-uname_db1-').get()

uname_d1 = values['-uname_db1-']
```

and then you can use `.strip()` because someone may put spaces

```
uname_d1 = window.FindElement('-uname_db1-').get().strip()

uname_d1 = values['-uname_db1-'].strip()
```

---

You check `Test_DB1` and `Test_DB2` also in wrong way. It need

```
(Test_DB1 != True) and (Test_DB2 != True)
```

or better

```
if (Test_DB1 is not True) and (Test_DB2 is not True):

if (Test_DB1 is False) and (Test_DB2 is False):

if (not Test_DB1) and (not Test_DB2):
```

---

You could use `True/False` instead of `1/0` in secondwindow.

And it can be better to set default values before `while` loop

```
secondwindow = True
Test_DB1 = False
Test_DB2 = False
```

if you don't assign then and you click directly `Process`then you get error `name 'Test_DB1' is not defined` because it didn't run `Test_DB1 = createCon(...)` yet.

---

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import re
import datacompy
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd


def read_query(connection, query):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
       cursor.execute( query )
       header = [x[0] for x in cursor.description]
       rows = cursor.fetchall()
       return header, rows
    finally:
       if cursor is not None:
           cursor.close()

def create_con(user_name, password, host_name, port_number, service_name):

    dsn_str = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host=host_name,
                                port=port_number,
                                service_name=service_name)
    con = cx_Oracle.connect(user=user_name, password=password, dsn=dsn_str)
    
    return con
      
# --- main ---

DB_creds_one = [
     [
        sg.Text("UserName"),
        sg.In(size=(30, 2), enable_events=True, key="-uname_db1-")
     ],
     [
        sg.Text("Password"),
        sg.In(size=(30, 1), enable_events=True, key="-pword_db1-")
     ],
     [
        sg.Text("Hostname"),
        sg.In(size=(30, 1), enable_events=True, key="-hname_db1-")
     ],
     [
        sg.Text("Service Name"),
        sg.In(size=(30, 1), enable_events=True, key="-sname_db1-")
     ],
     [
        sg.Text("Port"),
        sg.In(size=(30, 1), enable_events=True, key="-port_db1-")
     ],
     [   
        sg.Button('Test Con1', key='B1')
     ],
]

DB_creds_two = [
    [
        sg.Text("UserName"),
        sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-uname_db2-")
    ],
    [
        sg.Text("Password"),
        sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-pword_db2-")
    ],
    [
        sg.Text("Hostname"),
        sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-hname_db2-")
    ],
    [
        sg.Text("Service Name"),
        sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-sname_db2-")
    ],
    [
        sg.Text("Port"),
        sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-port_db2-")
    ],
    [   
        sg.Button('Test Con2',key='B2')
    ],

]


layoutprefile = [
    [ 
        sg.Column(DB_creds_one),
        sg.VSeperator(),
        sg.Column(DB_creds_two),
    ],
    [sg.Output(size=(61, 5), key='-output-')],
    [sg.Submit('Proceed'), sg.Cancel('Exit')]
]
 
window = sg.Window("DB Comparator", layoutprefile)

# default values at start
secondwindow = True
Test_DB1 = False
Test_DB2 = False

while True:    # The Event Loop
    event, values = window.read()
    # print(event, values)  # debug
    if event in (None, 'Exit', 'Cancel'):
        secondwindow = False
        break
    elif event == 'B1':
        # Test DB Connection 1  return Test_DB1
        uname_d1 = values['-uname_db1-'].strip()
        pword_d1 = values['-pword_db1-'].strip()
        hname_d1 = values['-hname_db1-'].strip()
        sname_d1 = values['-sname_db1-'].strip()
        port_d1  = values['-port_db1-'].strip()

        print()
        
        #if uname_d1 == '' or pword_d1 == '' or hname_d1 == '' or sname_d1 == '' and port_d1 == '':
        #if not all([uname_d1, pword_d1, hname_d1, sname_d1, port_d1]):
        if '' in (uname_d1, pword_d1, hname_d1, sname_d1, port_d1):
            print("Enter values")
        else:
            Test_DB1 = create_con(uname_d1, pword_d1, hname_d1, sname_d1, port_d1)
            
    elif event == 'B2':
        # Test DB Connection 2 return Test_DB2
        uname_d2 = values['-uname_db2-'].strip()
        pword_d2 = values['-pword_db2-'].strip()
        hname_d2 = values['-hname_db2-'].strip()
        sname_d2 = values['-sname_db2-'].strip()
        port_d2  = values['-port_db2-'].strip()
        
        #if uname_d2 == '' or pword_d2 == '' or hname_d2 == '' or sname_d2 == '' and port_d1 == '':
        #if not all([uname_d2, pword_d2, hname_d2, sname_d2, port_d2]):
        if '' in (uname_d2, pword_d2, hname_d2, sname_d2, port_d2):
            print("Enter values")
        else:
            Test_DB2 = create_con(uname_d2, pword_d2, hname_d2, sname_d2, port_d2)

    if event == 'Proceed':
        if not Test_DB1 and not Test_DB2:
            sg.Popup("Incorrect Database Details Please Verify the Connection Again")
        else:
            window.close()
            break

#    if not secondwindow:
exit()
```

Comment: Hi @furas, after using .strip() function the values are getting printed as per whatever text box holds but i am facing another issue, whenever i am passing those uname_d1,pword_d2 .... to createCon() it's not able to make a database connection, i tried getting the exact error string it displays this " Database connection error: %s ", what am i missing here or should is change the function ? 
I Did passed the exact DB details in that function i was able to connect to the database problem occurs when i am trying to store them in a var and then passing the var to the function

Comment: if you have new problem then you should create new question on new page. Or at least you could add it to current question - it will be more readable. I don't have cx_Oracle so I can't check it but first I would use `print(...)` `print(type(...))` to see values in variables. Maybe you have wrong values in variables.  Maybe you used wrong variables. I hope you don't use space in database configuration because `.strip()` removes it from values.

Comment: sure i will put up a new question for the same, 
and i did verified the values in those var they are the expected values but still not able to connect

Comment: maybe @JasonYang has right and you have to convert `port numer` to `integer` - widgets give all as text (even numbers) but database may need number instead of text.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks not well formatted.

Some issues listed here,

1. wrong layout

```py
layoutprefile = [
    [
        sg.Column(DB_creds_one),
        sg.VSeperator(),
        sg.Column(DB_creds_two),
       [sg.Output(size=(61, 5), key='-output-')],
       [sg.Submit('Proceed'), sg.Cancel('Exit')]
    
    ]
]
```

If you need horizontal layout

```py
layout = [
    [sg.Button("Hello1"), sg.VerticalSeparator(), sg.Button("Hello2")],
]
```

or vertical layout

```py
layout = [
    [sg.Button("Hello1")],
    [sg.HorizontalSeparator()],
    [sg.Button("Hello2")],
]
```

2. Wrong method to get value of sg.Input

```py
uname_d1 = window.FindElement('-uname_db1-')    # It can be window['-uname_db1-']
```

It just gets the element of element `sg.input`. To get value of `sg.Input`

```py
uname_d1 = values['-uname_db1-']
```

3. If both values of `Test_DB1` and `Test_DB2` in following logical statement will get wrong result

```py
if (Test_DB1 and Test_DB2 != 'True'):
```

Maybe it should be

```py
if not (Test_DB1 and Test_DB2):
```

4. Wrong order of arguments for function `create_con` when called.

```py
#      def createCon(uname,   passw,   hname,   portnum, sname):
Test_DB1 = createCon(uname_d1,pword_d1,hname_d1,sname_d1,port_d1)
```

5. `portnum` may be converted into an interger before passing to function `createCon`

Comment: Hi Jason, i used .strip() function to get the values and they are getting printed as per whatever text box holds but i am facing another issue, whenever i am passing those uname_d1,pword_d2 .... to createCon() it's not able to make a database connection, i tried getting the exact error string it displays this " Database connection error: %s ", what am i missing here or should is change the function ? I Did passed the exact DB details in that function i was able to connect to the database problem occurs when i am trying to store them in a var and then passing the var to the function

Comment: Maybe you give wrong order of arguments, `def createCon(uname,passw,hname,portnum,sname)` vs `createCon(uname_d2,pword_d2,hname_d2,sname_d2,port_d2)`. `portnum` vs `sname`

Comment: You should convert `portnum` into an integer if it should be an integer.

Comment: Hi, i did verify the result's by printing them it's picking up the result as it is but still not able to connect to a DB and the sequence also confirmed

Comment: You can confirm what arguments passed by calling `print(repr(uname_D1))` before call `createCon`. If all arguments correct, then I have no answer for you about `cx_Oracle`.

Comment: sure Thank you i will confirm the values by using print(repr(uname_D1)) 
thank you